# How to reinstall MVC 2 tools for VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

I accidentally uninstalled the Asp.Net MVC 2 Tools for Visual Studio 2010.  How can I reinstall it?  The MVC2 download only seems to include the VS2008 tools.

Everything I've googled says that MVC 2 is included in VS2010, but a repair install didn't fix it, and MVC 2 isn't listed as a selectable component in the VS2010's add/remove components screen.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You'll find VS2010ToolsMVC2.msi on your VS2010 DVD under WCU\ASPNETMVC - hopefully that will do it!