# How can I reinstall MVC2 in VS2010 Ultimate?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

Some how I lost MVC2? I have MVC3 bit 2 is goner. I have uninstalled and reinstalled with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you need to reinstall your default project templates.

1. In the command prompt, navigate to the location of devenv.exe. This file is located in `<Visual Studio Installation Path>\Common7\IDE`.
2. Type "devenv /installvstemplates" and press Enter.

Reference here

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247116.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Please refer to [How to reinstall MVC 2 tools for VS2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5326793/how-to-reinstall-mvc-2-tools-for-vs2010)

**Reinstalling MVC2 for Visual studio 2010:**

VS2010ToolsMVC2.msi on your VS2010 DVD under WCU\ASPNETMVC.

this should fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In the end a "repair" on .NET 4.0 frameworks fixed the issue.